# js - set var = width of element with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a script for outputting google map , and I am using infobox

in my script , I have a "dnamic" width for the infobox, which works just fine .
The problem is that I need to set the "close" button margins ..
The infobox takes an element with class of "infobox".

```
var s_infobox_k = {
             content: "z",
             disableAutoPan: false,
             maxWidth: 0,
             zIndex: null,
             boxStyle: { 
             padding: "10px",
             width: "150px"
             },
             closeBoxMargin: "-14px", // <-- HERE I NEED THE WIDTH OF THE DIV
             closeBoxURL: pluginDir + "/images/close.png",
                 isHidden: false,
             pane: "floatPane",
             enableEventPropagation: false
        };
```

basically I need the closeBoxMargin to be `" closeBoxMargin: "-14px InfoboxWidth()px",`

so I tired to set a VAR

```
var width_div = jQuery(\'.infobox\').width() ;
```

but for some reason it is only printing the exact same syntax in the JS . (e.g. in the JS i will see -  `var width_div = jQuery(\'.infobox\').width() ;` ) - literraly , instead of `var width_div = valuePx`.

Is that some syntax error ? or am I doing something terribly wrong ? why is the var no getting set ?

**EDIT 1 :**

This all javascript is being produced by an ultra simple php..

```
    function print_front_script() {
    return '
    <script type="text/javascript">
            ... script here 
</script>
    ';}
```

there are absolutly no other problems ..
even setting the var with PHP works great

```
closeBoxMargin: "-14px -'.((($this->innerthumbs_w)/2)+50).'px",
```

the problem is that PHP can not know the div width ...

**EDIT II**

the full script can be viewed here :
http://codepad.org/cC1qGPbV

**EDIT III** 
added the xHTML OUTPUT 
http://codepad.org/YdnMoVLq

Answer (score 3):

Probably just syntax. your variable s_infobox_k is an object containing properties. You don't need to define variables in order to set a property.

```
closeBoxMargin: jQuery('.infobox').width(),
```

[added] I might also be misunderstanding what you want the value of closeBoxMargin to be. Does it need to be literally a string that looks like `"-14px InfoboxWidth()px"`? Or does it need to be something like `"-14px 200px"` where 200px is the width of InfoboxWidth? I'm going to assume the latter... so instead of just going right to the width, we need to build a string. The cheapest and easiest way to do this is to just concatenate what you need:

```
closeBoxMargin: "14px " + jQuery('.infobox').width() + "px",
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7KAKY/1/

#### Bonus for giggles

If that "14px" is a relatively static value but has the potential to change from time to time, it could be stored in a variable external to the object. The `.infobox` width could also be stored externally. And then you could either concatenate the string externally before building the properties object, or you could do it inside the properties. Here's an example of the former:

```
var marginOffset = 14,
    infoWidth = jQuery('.infobox').width(),
    closeBoxString = marginOffset + "px " + infoWidth + "px";


var s_infobox_k = {
  // ... 
    closeBoxMargin: closeBoxString,
  // ...
};
```

Note that I don't store the "px" with the 14 or the info width. They're already integers this way, ready to be used for any other functions involving calculations. By concatenating with strings, the final result is still a string.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7KAKY/2/

Comment: thanks for the answer - but what you suggested produces the same exact result - it just prints the exact same thing in the JS...

Comment: yes, it needs to be a value like : ´ -14px 200px  ´ - but what I get from your code is the exact same result .. I get ´ closeBoxMargin: "14px " + jQuery('.infobox').width() + "px", ´ - can it be an escaping problem ?

Comment: I saw it works on your fiddle, and it also worked for me in the past every time - but now it fails, and I have no Idea why. not only that it fails, it just returnes the string ... it does not even produce a JS error on the console .

Comment: yes.. because this javascript is being prepared by PHP according to user variables .. this is exactly why I need to set a dynamic variable . I can always use ob_start() and file() in PHP - but it will over complicate things a lot , and will also require to write a new JS file on every http request ..

Comment: Deleted some old comments we ran through in a chat. It seems to me that if you're always getting a string only when trying to use function from within the s_infobox_k object, that maybe it's whatever's USING the object that's converting to a string.

Answer (score 0):

If the width is set by CSS, you could always just use:

```
var width_div = $('.infobox').css('width');
```

Which will return (for example): `500px`

If it is not using CSS, and you're just setting it with width="500", you can use:

```
var width_div = $('.infobox').attr('width');
```

Which will return (for example): `500`

And to add this into what you're trying to do, you would do:

```
closeBoxMargin: "-14px " + width_div,
```

**EDIT #1**

Well since you keep getting the literal string, you could try to fix it by pre-building a string instead of building the value on the fly.

Like so:

```
var closeBoxMarginValue = "14px " + $('.infobox').css('width');
```

And just dropping it in:

```
closeBoxMargin: closeBoxMarginValue,
```

See if that works.

Comment: thanks for trying to help - much appreciated . but the problem is not exactly about how to get the property. the problem is that it is just not working - it comes back as a string containing the jQuery function itself !

Comment: @Obmerk Ninenine, See Edit #1

Comment: still no go - It is still printing as a string ... no matter how i construct the var ..